# Nobody likes this compound word

Tags: word, wordplay, no-computers

> This compound word, that no-one likes, is made up of 3 consecutive words.
>
> Also made up of 2 consecutive words.
>
> Also the prefix and suffix are identical words
>
> Uses only 3 consonants.

Can you guess?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

EDITED WITH NEW ANSWER
Are you a

> headache

Three consecutive words

> he  ad  ache

Two consecutive words

> head ache

prefix and suffix the same

> **HE**adac**HE**

Three consonants

> uses H, D and C (h is used twice)

Nobody likes

> having a headache

And as a bonus

> Fits Chowzen's and El-Guest's definition of compound

OLDER GUESSES 
Are you an

> Orator ?

Three consecutive words

> or at or  (first and last are the same)

Two consecutive words

> ora - old english money  and tor - a high craggy hill

3 consonants

> r t r

Nobody likes it

> well nobody likes a long winded orator

Or perhaps it is

> a Tomato?

Three consecutive words

> to ma to   (first and last are the same)

Two consecutive words

> tom - as in a cat and ato  - a political division of a Bontok village

3 consonants

> t m t

Nobody likes it

> I know I don't!

Comment: @El-Guest I think it depends on the sense of "compound word".  They certainly are composed of smaller words (3 2-letter and 2 3-letter) which fits one definition of "compound".

Comment: Steve: that was a stupid comment of mine to make, you're right.

Comment: For the record, I don't believe either of those actually qualify as a compound word. A compound word puts two distinct words together *using their original meanings to create a new word.* I don't believe that an 'orator' has anything to do with old English money on a high craggy hill, or that 'tomato' has a meaning that has to do with a political division of a Bontok village made up of cats.  Compare to 'shipwreck' (a ship that has been wrecked), milkshake, mailbox, etc.

Comment: @chowzen I agree that it doesn't fit that definition of a compound word.  However, that is only one definition of compound according to Webster's unabridged, for which they give examples "rowboat, fireman, high school, devil-may-care, airtight, outrun, thereby, whereas, into".  Another definition is a word and a combining form such as centimeter or a word and a inflectional affix such as "builder, reenter".  I think orator fits into that one.   And a more general interpretation of compound could possibly include to-ma-to.  But I don't really think that "nobody likes" either of my answers.

Comment: Headache is a simple correct answer

Comment: I'm struggling a bit with what is passing for the prefix/suffix clue from a linguistics stand point, but some decent answers nonetheless

Comment: @Chowzen thank you for formalizing what I was thinking when I read compound word. SteveV, congratulations on the great answer! +1 from me!

Comment: For the record, big +1 on "headache!"

Answer (score 12):

I think it might be

> meantime

This word, that no-one likes,

> Meantime implies waiting for something; people usually don't like to wait.

is made up of 3 consecutive words.

> Me, anti, me

Also made up of 2 consecutive words.

> Mean, time

Also the prefix and suffix are identical words

> me

Uses only 3 consonants.

> m, n and t

Answer (score 8):

Hope this qualifies, otherwise I'll need an

> ERASER.

This word is made up of 3 consecutive words.

> [Er](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/er), [As](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/as), Er

Also made up of 2 consecutive words.

> [Eras](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/eras), Er

Also the prefix and suffix are identical words

> **er**as**er**

Uses only 3 consonants.

> e**r**a**s**e**r**

(And at this point I finally take a look at the title. Please put all relevant constraints in the question itself.)

Comment: It could refer to one of Arnold Schwarzenegger's movies that few people enjoyed

Answer (score 5):

I think the answer might be

> Outshout

This word, that no-one likes,

> Nobody likes being shouted over

is made up of 3 consecutive words.

> Out + sh + out

Also made up of 2 consecutive words.

> Out + shout

Also the prefix and suffix are identical words

> Out

Uses only 3 consonants.

> h,s and t

Answer (score 0):

The only answer I could come up with:

> okeydokey

This compound word,

> okeydokey = okey + dokey

that no-one likes,

> Who admits to using it?  (Okay, maybe Ned Flanders.)

is made up of 3 consecutive words.

> okeydokey = o + key + dokey

or:

> okeydokey = okey + do + key

Also made up of 2 consecutive words.

> okeydokey = okey + dokey

Also the prefix and suffix are identical words

> okey(d)okey

Uses only 3 consonants.

> d, k, and k.

Bonus!  Also made up of 4 consecutive words:

> okeydokey = o + key + do + key

Answer (score 0):

Another answer:

> meantime

This compound word,

> meantime = mean + time

that no-one likes,

> Nobody likes it when it's time to be mean.

is made up of 3 consecutive words.

> meantime = me + an + time

Also made up of 2 consecutive words.

> meantime = mean + time

Also the prefix and suffix are identical words

> "meantime" starts and ends with "me"

Uses only 3 consonants.

> m, n, and t.

Bonus!  Also produces a burst of energy:

> me + anti-me = burst of energy you get when matter and anti-matter collide.